# react-navigation : undefined navigation props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I have a `react-navigation` router like so:

```
const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  App: createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreenContainer
    },
    Scan: {
      screen: DocumentScanScreenContainer
    },
    // ...
  }, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      // ...
    }
  })
})
```

The `HomeScreenContainer` and `DocumentScanScreenContainer` are required because `react-navigation` accepts only `React.Component`, and my `HomeScreen` and `DocumentScanScreen` components are Redux components and importing them directly makes `react-navigation` throwing error.

`HomeScreenContainer` and `DocumentScanScreenContainer` are similar, so here is the `DocumentScanScreenContainer`:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import DocumentScanScreen from '../../screens/DocumentScanScreen'

export default class DocumentScanScreenContainer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.shape.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props

    // Passing the navigation object to the screen so that you can call
    // this.props.navigation.navigate() from the screen.
    return (
      <DocumentScanScreen navigation={navigation} />
    )
  }
}
```

And finally a short version of the `DocumentScanScreen`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class DocumentScanScreen extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    token: PropTypes.string,
    navigation: PropTypes.shape.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { token, navigation } = this.props
    if (token === undefined || token === null || token === 0) {
      navigation.navigate('Authentication')
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

I have warnings at each levels stating that `navigation` is undefined, so it's like my `DocumentScanScreenContainer` isn't receiving the `navigation` prop from the router :

> Warning: Failed prop type: DocumentScanScreenContainer: prop type `navigation` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.

Am I doing it wrong or is there a way to pass, from the router, the `navigation` prop to the `DocumentScanScreenContainer` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Scan: {
  screen: (props) => <DocumentScanScreenContainer {...props} />
},
```

---

*I'm not sure if this will work but I can't add a comment because I have < 50 rep

Comment: Hey thank you ! I will try that as soon as possible !